# Unique methods to generate sudoku puzzle

Tags: algorithm, puzzle, sudoku

How many possible unique ways are there to generate a Sudoku Puzzle?? 
I can think of only two possible ways
1) Take a solved Sudoku puzzle and shuffle the rows and columns
2) Generate a random number and check if it violates any Sudoku constraints, repeat untill number does not violate any Sudoku constraint for every square(theoretically possible but normally it leads to deadlocking )

Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Here](http://zhangroup.aporc.org/images/files/Paper_3485.pdf) is a 20-page PDF, titled "Sudoku Puzzles Generating: from Easy to Evil", that you'd probably find useful in your quest.

To answer your question:

> Are there any other ways?

Yes. Yes there are.

Answer (score -2):

Simple way to generate up to Take a Solved Sudoko puzzle, 
step 1 ) replace all 1 with A , 2 with B till 9 with I,
Step 2) do a shuffle in each horizontal and vertical block block of using a random between 1 and 3, here in each there can only be 3 possible combinations.
step 3) now shuffle the block there can only be 3 vertical and 3 horizontal shuffle 
step 4) rotate the block 1 to 4 time..
step 5) mirror the puzzle vertically and horizontally using a random between 1 and 2.
step 6) replace all A with any number 1 to 9..

guessing this will produce around 38,093,690,880 combos....